# Is there a way to subclass/inherit/extend the javascript WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, websocket

I've looked everywhere and it doesn't seem like there are any questions let alone answers out there regarding this.

I've tried multiple ways and using prototypal inheritance seemed like it would be the best way

```
function MyWebSocket(url) {
  // do other stuff
  WebSocket.call(this, url);
}

MyWebSocket.prototype = Object.create(WebSocket.prototype);
MyWebSocket.prototype.constructor = MyWebSocket;
MyWebSocket.prototype.test = function () { alert('hi'); };
```

I can assign the test function alone just fine but in trying to override the consutructor I get the error "TypeError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function" from chrome.

I understand that this is not your typical javascript function/object but I would really like a way to override the WebSocket constructor to set in motion other maintenance functions such as a ping interval and yes I can do this individually in the onopen functions but this is something I want to just be global to all WebSockets opened on the site.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Well, you have to build an instance of WebSocket inside the constructor function. Now you have a choice: either aggregate this as a property, and use it via adapters, or use something like `Object.setPrototypeOf(this.__proto__, new WebSocket(url));`. Be aware the latter isn't supported by Safari.

Comment: Actually, it's better written as `Object.setPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this), new WebSocket(url))`.

Comment: I wish the second method would have worked but that causes issues with anonymous functions (like getters/setters for the event functions) not being bound to a WebSocket so Chrome throws Illegal Invocation and Firefox throws "TypeError: 'onmessage' setter called on an object that does not implement interface WebSocket"

Comment: I'm just going to use an adapter for it.  I wanted to stay away from that because it's very verbose and it has to be kept up to date with even possibly minor changes to the WebSocket API.  Hopefully we won't see anything like that often though.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following could work for you:

```
function MyWebSocket(url) {
     this.ws = new WebSocket(url);

}

MyWebSocket.prototype.test = (function() { 
   // this = MyWebSocket.ws, i.e. a plain WebSocket obj
}).bind(MyWebSocket.ws);

var myWS = new MyWebSocket(url);
myWS.test(); // does something to the underlying websocket
```

Or alternately, to do something to the underlying websocket, you could not use `bind` and instead just refer to `this.ws` when defining the functions on `MyWebSocket.prototype`.

Comment: Yes but the test function works as I want it to on its own.  It's the constructor I want to override.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I ended up doing, thank you for the help